# How do I redirect stdout from one process to be read as file descriptor 3 in another?

Tags: bash, sh, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I want to redirect (stdout,stderr) from one process to (stdin,file descriptor 3) of another.  How do I do that?

For example, if I have `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# myscript.sh
echo "stdout"
echo "stderr" >&2
```

And `reader.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# reader.sh
read key
echo "stdin: $key"
read key <&3
echo "fd3: $key"
```

How do I pipe the output of `myscript.sh` to `reader.sh` such that the final output is:

```
stdin: stdout
fd3: stderr
```

The closest I've gotten is:

```
./myscript.sh 2>&3 | ./reader.sh
```

But that hangs waiting for input (from fd 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with a named pipe:

```
mkfifo err 
./myscript.sh 2>err | ./reader.sh 3<err
```

Doing 2>&3 in your attempt just sends stderr to wherever the parent shell has 3 pointed, and will fail if you haven't already opened 3 in that shell.  It doesn't do any good for the reader shell's 3; even if inherited, it would be as a write fd, not a read one.

Comment: Thank you, Mark!  I just stumbled on `mkfifo`.  Is there no way to do this without a named pipe?

Comment: On Linux there are some ways; on macOS you need the named pipe, though you can hide it away somewhere. See https://superuser.com/questions/184307/bash-create-anonymous-fifo/1405693#1405693