# Pipe stdout to command which itself needs to read from own stdin

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to get the stdout from a process into another process not using stdin, as that one is used for another purpose.

In short I want to accomplish something like that:

```
echo  "a" >&4
cat | grep -f /dev/fd/4
```

I got it running using an file as source for file descriptor 4, but that is not what I want:

```
# Variant 1
cat file | grep -f /dev/fd/4 4<pattern

# Variant 2
exec 4<pattern
cat | grep -f /dev/fd/4
exec 4<&-
```

My best try is that, but I got the following error message:

```
# Variant 3
cat | ( 
    echo  "a" >&4
    grep -f /dev/fd/4
) <&4
```

Error message:

```
test.sh: line 5: 4: Bad file descriptor
```

What is the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use multiple streams to do this:

```
$ printf foo > pattern
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar | grep -f pattern
foo
```

If instead of a static file you want to use the output of a command as the input to `-f` you can use a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism):

```
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar | grep -f <(echo foo)
foo
```

Comment: Ah, I got process substitution wrong: even `grep -f <(echo FOO) -i` would work for example.
But isn't there any way to do it piping around. I seems to me more readable... (but perhaps that is a wrong assumption)

Comment: Can you have a look to some similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715318/

Answer (score 0):

For *POSIX* shells that lack *process substitution*, (e.g. `dash`, `ash`, `yash`, *etc.*).

If the command allows string input, (`grep` allows it), and the input string containing search targets isn't especially large, (i.e. the string doesn't exceed the [length limit for the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit/19355351#19355351)), there's always [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

```
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar baz | grep $(echo foo)
foo
```

Or if the input file is multi-line, separating quoted search items with '*\n*' works  the same as `grep` *OR* `\|`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar baz | grep "$(printf "%s\n" foo bar)"
foo
bar
```

Comment: The input is large and has serveral lines (several patterns for `grep`). @l0b0 solution matches better.

Comment: @doak, Re "*several lines*": that doesn't sound that large.  For the *multi-line* version of the above code to fail, the byte length of the whole list of target strings would need to be (almost) greater than the output of `getconf ARG_MAX`, (*e.g.* on my current system that's *2097152*).

Comment: It is a good alternative without process substituion. Nevertheless I don't like the additional `sed` in the multi-line version.

Comment: @doak, Thanks!  Your comment lead to the discovery that the `sed` portion was unnecessary, it seems that newlines in a quoted string mean *OR* to `grep` -- or at least to *GNU* `grep`.